# How to combine two commands into one under unix?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, ubuntu

Usually i start debug a java program by type `jdb` in terminal, then it will enter debugging mode, then i can input something like "stop at com.android.contacts.dirtyImport.DirtyImportManager:95" to tell jdb to stop at certain line.

Now here is the question: how can i combine these two cmds input one. Something like "jdb < stop at com.android.contacts.dirtyImport.DirtyImportManager:95". The reason i have this requirement is that i want to let vim automatic generate debug info and enter debug mode, stop make breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to prepend a line to the standard input:

```
{ echo "stop at com.android.contacts.dirtyImport.DirtyImportManager:95"; cat; } | jdb
```

This starts a subshell (`{}`) that first prints the given line with `echo` and then reads the standard input and prints the read lines to the standard output (`cat`). The whole input is piped into jdb.

This, however, confuses some programs that distinguish between terminal input and pipe input. In this case, you'll want to have a look at the program's reference, as debuggers often support executing commands from a file (as `gdb` with `-x`).

Comment: Can i plus this answer twice? You are totally a genius. I have searching this answer so long. But i still don't know what does `{` and cat used for? Could you give me any hints? Because after i remove any part of your command i won't run as i wish. Thank you again.

Comment: @user674199: Thanks. Expanded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you might looking into generating `expect` scripts. [Here is a tutorial](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/128384), which does something with `gdb` automation.